# Find an error in the convolution of 2 pdfs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X\sim \exp(2)$ and  $Y\sim \exp(3)$ I was asked to find $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ but this is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(X-Y>0)$. Pdf's of $X$ and $-Y$ are $f_X(x)=2e^{-2x}$ and $f_{-Y}(y)=-3e^{-3y}$ respectively. So let $Z=X-Y$ then

$
\begin{align}
f_Z(t)=f_{X-Y}(t)=f_X*f_{-Y}(t)&=\int_\mathbb{R} -3e^{-(3t-x)}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t-x)2e^{-2x}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)
\\&= \int_\mathbb{R} -3e^{-3x}\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,t)}(x)2e^{-2x}\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)
\\&=\int_\mathbb{R}-6e^{-5x}\mathbb{1}_{[-\infty,t]\cap[0,\infty)}(x)
\\&=\int_0^t-6e^{-5x}
\\&= \frac{6}{5} (-1 + e^{-5 t})\end{align}$

So $$F(t)=\int_0^t\frac{6}{5} (-1 + e^{-5 t})=\frac{6}{5} (-1 + e^{-5 t}) t$$

but then as $t\to\infty$ one gets that $F(t)$ diverges $$\lim_{t\to \infty}F(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{6}{5} (-1 + e^{-5 t}) t =\infty\neq 1$$

So $F(t)$ is not a CDF and in consequence $f_Z(t)$ not PDF.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: $f_{-Y}(y)$ cannot be $-3e^{-3y}$ because the density is a nonnegative function but yours is negative. In fact the desired probability is $\int_0^\infty P(X>y).dP(Y\le y) = \int_0^\infty e^{-2y}3e^{-3y}dy =\frac{3}{5}.$

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong, but since those functions are exponentials, why not do it with convolution theorem in Fourier domain?

Comment: Besides what kmitov has said you should realize that $Z$ is not a positive random variable so you have to consider $f_Z(t)$ for $t <0$ also.

Comment: @kmitov I know how to solve it. For example using the law of total probability, however I wanted to use convolution for practice. Thanks for pointing out that $f_{-Y}$ is wrong.

Comment: I have corrected your title : you **convolve** pdfs whereas you **add** the corresponding RVs.

Comment: Actually you should add to your question the information that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: In general with independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ following exponential distributions with rates $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \ldots$, the first to occur/minimum is also exponentially distributed, with rate $\sum\limits_j \lambda_j$, and the probability that the first/minimum is $X_i$ is $\dfrac{\lambda_i}{\sum\limits_j \lambda_j}$. So here the probability that $Y$ is less than $X$ is $\dfrac{3}{2+3}$.  You can then use memorylessness to get the conditional distribution of $X-Y$ when it is positive and when it is negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_{X}\left(x\right)=2e^{-2x}\mathbf{1}_{\left(0,\infty\right)}\left(x\right)$
and $f_{-Y}\left(y\right)=f_{Y}\left(-y\right)=3e^{3y}\mathbf{1}_{\left(0,\infty\right)}\left(-y\right)$
leading to:

$$\left(f_{X}\ast f_{Y}\right)\left(t\right)=\int2e^{-2z}\mathbf{1}_{\left(0,\infty\right)}\left(z\right)3e^{3t-3z}\mathbf{1}_{\left(0,\infty\right)}\left(3z-3t\right)dz=6e^{3t}\int_{\max\left\{ 0,t\right\} }^{\infty}e^{-5z}dz$$

Then we discern the cases $t>0$ and $t\leq0$.

- If $t>0$ then $\left(f_{X}\ast f_{Y}\right)\left(t\right)=6e^{3t}\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{-5z}dz=6e^{3t}\times\frac{1}{5}e^{-5t}=\frac{6}{5}e^{-2t}$.
- If $t\leq0$ then $\left(f_{X}\ast f_{Y}\right)\left(t\right)=6e^{3t}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-5z}dz=\frac{6}{5}e^{3t}$

Then: $$P(X>Y)=P(X-Y>0)=\int\frac{6}{5}e^{-2t}dt=\frac35$$

It is more handsome here to go for:$$P(X>Y)=\int_0^{\infty} P(X>Y\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)dy=$$$$\int_0^{\infty} P(X>y)f_Y(y)dy=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2y}3e^{-3y}dy=\frac35$$

Comment: thanks for your help. This exercise has also second part that asks for the $\mathbb{P}(X-Y>t |X>Y)$ I solved it as follows:
$\mathbb{P}(X-Y>t |X>Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-Y>t \ \text{and} \ X-Y>0)\mathbb{P}(X>Y)^{-1}$ So for $t<0$ we get $\mathbb{P}(X-Y>t |X>Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-Y>0)\mathbb{P}(X>Y)^{-1}=1$ and for $t\geq0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(X-Y>t |X>Y)=\mathbb{P}(X-Y>t)\mathbb{P}(X>Y)^{-1}=1-e^{-5t}$ Is it right ? Can you think of some other solution to this where we need to use independence of $X, Y$?

Comment: Correct for $t<0$ and for $t>0$ the expression $\mathbb P(X-Y>t)\mathbb P(X>Y)^{-1}$ is okay. Then things go wrong. Based on my answer you can find that $P\left(X-Y>t\right)=\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{6}{5}e^{-2z}dz=\frac{3}{5}e^{-2t}$
so that $\mathbb P(X-Y>t\mid X>Y)=e^{-2t}$.

Comment: Another route to that result is: $$P\left(X-Y>t\mid X>Y\right)=\frac{P\left(X-Y>t\wedge X>Y\right)}{P\left(X>Y\right)}=\frac{5}{3}P\left(X>Y+t\right)=$$$$\frac{5}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X>Y+t\mid Y=y\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy=\frac{5}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}P\left(X>y+t\right)f_{Y}\left(y\right)dy=$$$$\frac{5}{3}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2y-2t}3e^{-3y}dy=5e^{-2t}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-5y}dy=e^{-2t}$$The independence is used in both routes (the convolution for $X-Y$ rests on it, and the third equality above does).